# Как сделать что бы Django распознавал кириллицу?

Tags: django

Если в коде встречается кирилличные символы, или что то задокументировано в кириллице то выдает ошибку, как это исправить глобально для всего проекта, а не только для одного документа.

Answer (score 4):

В начале файла

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

И использовать юникодные строки:

```
str = u'Моя строка'
```

Comment: <pre># -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- не помогает</pre>

Comment: Напишите, что у Вас за ошибка. Django сам по себе отлично работает с кириллицей.

Comment: Извините, все уже работает и не выдает ошибку, чудеса )

Comment: Хотя есть еще вот такая проблема, когда в поле для голосования ввожу ответ на кириллице выдает ошибку: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Выложите полный traceback, одной строчки мало. И проверьте кодировку базы данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in inner
  339.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1232.                 change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, formsets)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in construct_change_message
  811.                                              'object': force_text(added_object)})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
  108.                     s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/polls/poll/2/
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: traceback это то, что в консоли при этом получается.

Comment: Нужно что бы db была в utf-8? Если да, то как сделать, если по умолчанию она в ANSI.

Comment: Проверьте кодировку скрипта (.ру). Сталкивался с такой проблемой, когда случайно сохранил скрипт в кодировке ср1251